# How to disable special character escaping of a java Node

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have a function in which I create a Node and set it textContent to a special character for example a bullet (•). This function is called in an xsl:apply-templates. However, the output escape the special caracter and instead of seeing a bullet, • appears on my result. After doing some research I haven't found any way to disable escaping from my node. My thesis is that the Node created is a CDATA section, but how can I revert that ?

Here is the code that I used to create the node :

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();                
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();                
Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
result = doc.createElement("doesntmatter");   
result.setTextContent("&#8226;");
```

Thanks for your help :)

Edit : Something like disable-output-escaping in xslt but for java Element/node should do the trick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `setTextContent` but then providing the escaped version - you should let the API do the escaping. You're currently trying to set the text content of the node to literally `"&#8226;"` - not a bullet. You probably just want:

```
result.setTextContent("\u2022");
```

to specify that the content should just be [U+2022 (bullet)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2022/index.htm) which is code point 8226 in decimal.